# fatal error while trying to send message using twilio Api phpSDK

Tags: php, twilio, fatal-error

When I use twilio I get following error:

> PHP Catchable fatal error:  Argument 2 passed to
>   Twilio\Rest\Api\V2010\Account\MessageInstance::__construct() **must be
>   of the type array**, null given, called in
>   /data/home/changliang/twilio/twilio-php-master/Twilio/Rest/Api/V2010/Account/MessageList.php
>   on line 69 and defined in
>   /data/home/changliang/twilio/twilio-php-master/Twilio/Rest/Api/V2010/Account/MessageInstance.php
>   on line 52

this is my code.

```
require_once("/twilio/twilio-php-master/Twilio/autoload.php");
use Twilio\Rest\Client;
$to = '+12022022022'
$content = 'hello';
$sid = 'XXXXXXX'; 
$token = 'XXXXXXXX'; 
$client = new Client($sid, $token);
$sms = $client->account->messages->create(  
    $to,
    array(
        'from' => '+12346788xx',
        'body' => $content,
    )  
);
```

Answer (score 3):

Had the same error. Is your request maybe made through a corporate proxy server? That was the issue here. The proxy server here adds an additional HTTP header to the response header and because of this the CurlClient does not correctly parses the response body:

> HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established

I got it fixed by adding an additional header to skip in CurlClient class around line 37:

Original:

```
list($head, $body) = ($parts[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 100 Continue')
                           ? array($parts[1], $parts[2])
                           : array($parts[0], $parts[1]);
```

New:

```
list($head, $body) = ($parts[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 100 Continue'
                   || $parts[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established')
                           ? array($parts[1], $parts[2])
                           : array($parts[0], $parts[1]);
```

Comment: works without any problems. Curl client is placed in directory: twilio_outbound_phone_call/twilio-php-master/Twilio/Http

Answer (score 1):

Bastian's fix worked for me, but it looks like the sdk might have changed a little since his response. For me it looked originally like:

```
list($head, $body) = (
    \preg_match('/\AHTTP\/1.\d 100 Continue\Z/', $parts[0])
    || \preg_match('/\AHTTP\/1.\d 200 Connection established\Z/', $parts[0])
    || \preg_match('/\AHTTP\/1.\d 200 Tunnel established\Z/', $parts[0])
)           ? array($parts[1], $parts[2])
            : array($parts[0], $parts[1]);
```

and the header my proxy was returning was:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

the fix for me was to add a regex to catch basically 200 header response:

```
list($head, $body) = (
    \preg_match('/\AHTTP\/1.\d 100 Continue\Z/', $parts[0])
    || \preg_match('/\AHTTP\/1.\d 200 Connection established\Z/', $parts[0])
    || \preg_match('/\AHTTP\/1.\d 200 Tunnel established\Z/', $parts[0])
    || \preg_match('/\AHTTP\/1.\d 200 .*/', $parts[0])
)           ? array($parts[1], $parts[2])
            : array($parts[0], $parts[1]);
```